# How can I binding combo's selectionIndex and Integer in Eclipse RCP application (SWT)?

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, jface, rcp

For binding String and Combo I can use this code:

```
IObservableValue comboTypeObserveTextObserveWidget = SWTObservables.observeText(comboType);
IObservableValue typeObserveValue = PojoObservables.observeValue(router.getParameters(), "type.data");
bindingContext.bindValue(comboTypeObserveTextObserveWidget, typeObserveValue, updateStrategy, null);
```

Where "type.data" is String.

But I want to bind combos's selectionIndex with Integer value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.SWTObservables.observeSingleSelectionIndex(Control)` for this purpose...

```
package test123;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import org.eclipse.core.databinding.AggregateValidationStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.UpdateValueStrategy;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.BeansObservables;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.IObservableValue;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.validation.IValidator;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.validation.ValidationStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.ISWTObservableValue;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.SWTObservables;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Test123 extends Shell {

    private static class Pojo<T> {
        private T data;

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            final Display display = Display.getDefault();
            Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display),
                    new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Test123 shell = new Test123(display);
                            shell.open();
                            shell.layout();
                            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                                    display.sleep();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the shell.
     * 
     * @param display
     */
    public Test123(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Combo combo = new Combo(this, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1,
                1));
        combo.setItems(new String[] { "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3" });
        createContents();
        final Pojo<Integer> pojo = new Pojo<Integer>();
        ISWTObservableValue swtObs = SWTObservables
                .observeSingleSelectionIndex(combo);

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false,
                false, 1, 1));
        IObservableValue modelObs = BeansObservables.observeValue(pojo, "data");
        final DataBindingContext dataBindingContext = new DataBindingContext();
        dataBindingContext.bindValue(swtObs, modelObs, new UpdateValueStrategy(
                UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT)
                .setAfterConvertValidator(new IValidator() {
                    @Override
                    public IStatus validate(Object value) {
                        if ((Integer) value == 1) {
                            return ValidationStatus
                                    .error("Test 2 is not allowed");
                        }
                        return ValidationStatus.ok();
                    }
                }), null);
        addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
                // this is neccessary since POLICY_CONVERT does not
                // automatically set the value to the model.
                dataBindingContext.updateModels();
                System.out.println(pojo.getData());
            }
        });
        ISWTObservableValue valiObs = SWTObservables.observeText(lblNewLabel);
        dataBindingContext.bindValue(valiObs, new AggregateValidationStatus(
                dataBindingContext.getBindings(),
                AggregateValidationStatus.MAX_SEVERITY));

    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the shell.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        setText("SWT Application");
        setSize(450, 300);

    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this code, I get `BindingException`: "converter does not convert from type int Expected: int, actual: class java.lang.String". But `type.data` is Java Integer.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! The problem was in `UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_CONVERT`. Somehow `POLICY_CONVERT` not supported with `observeSingleSelectionIndex`. How to replace `POLICY_CONVERT` functionality in this context?

Comment: Yes, it works. The problem was in `type.data`. Type of `data` field was defined by Java Generics parameter and after binding magically switch from Integer to String. After remove generics parameters, it works fine. Do you know why it works this way?

Comment: No this can't be the reason. I've introduced a generic parameter in the snippet. And it works...